# How to convert my site completely to angularjs?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I want my site to act realtime completely. There is a nodejs module which is easy to setup I guess with lot of other modules available to provide integration with nodejs.

There is also a module available to integrate ajax with nodejs on drupal as drupal site uses ajax, specially when we are using views. Just for information I have read that

> nodejs has some security issues and should not be used and angularjs
>   should be the choice.

How do I integrate the site with angularjs to make it a real-time application almost completely?

I know there are few modules like [ngapp](https://www.drupal.org/project/ngapp) and [Angularjs](https://www.drupal.org/project/angularjs), but do not know whether it is what I am looking for.

Note: If setting up angular is complex for a beginner like me, then I will prefer nodejs because it is easy to setup and some third-party modules also integrate with nodejs.

If I get proper guidance, I am willing to do the hard work.

Comment: The first part of the question, the one about node.js having security issues is off-topic for us, since eventual security issues don't depend from Drupal, or they would be Drupal security issues.

Comment: @kiamlaluno How can I make it better so that you remove on hold from my question?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have removed the first question which was related to nodejs security. Happy now?

Comment: I think there are several headless approaches for Drupal 7, and I am not sure that there is a "best answer". I've run a Drupal 7 site in a sub-directory with an angular.js front end, seen presentations on running mini-apps embedded into drupal pages, and lately a custom module that could provide a path to bootstrap an angular app (the reverse of the first thing). However with all that, you can't 100% be headless if you have users registering on the site because the password reset email *must* flow through Drupal's page router without rewriting the PHP for that entirely.

Comment: @mradcliffe What if do not want it to be 100% headless? How about 60-70%? Any solution available?

Comment: I explained it in my previous comment: "the password reset email must flow through Drupal's page router".

Comment: @mradcliffe I did not understand what you mean, but anyway thank you